# Проигрывание музыки с кнопки

Tags: swift

Как сделать, чтобы при первом нажатии на кнопке играла музыка, а при следующем останавливалась?

Comment: а что не получается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Добавить флаг, например `isPlaying` и по умолчанию его значение `false`.
2. Реализовать метод, отвечающий за клик на кнопку.
3. Добавить в него следующее:

   ```
   if isPlaying {  
       audioPlayer.pause()  
       isPlaying = false  
   } else {  
       audioPlayer.play()  
       isPlaying = true
   ```

Comment: Я новичок и немного не понимаю, что значит флаг?

Comment: @PRKan, просто булевская переменная, которая по умолчанию имеет значение, например, false. Затем использовать эту переменную в каком-неибудь методе. Перед выполнением кода в методе проверять значение этой переменной (флага), а после выполнения кода изменять значение флага (переменной) на противоположное, если требуется.

Comment: А как само аудио добавить?

Comment: @PRKan, это уже другой вопрос

Comment: @PRKan, по аналогии с андроидом, нужно создать объект плеера и оперировать с ним

Comment: ладно, спасибо.